# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'classList') at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous>

Tags: javascript, css, loops, class, addition

Attempting to add a class via js to HTML in order to change CSS styling after a "click" EventListener.

I tried to loop classList.add to the existing divs I wanted to be effected to no luck.

Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Etch-a-sketch</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
  <h2 class="title">Etch-a-Sketch</h2>
  <div class="container"></div>
  <div class="buttons">
    <button class="button-text">Grid Size</button>
    <button class="button-text"> Color</button>
    <button class="button-text">Reset</button>
  </div>


  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
const container = document.querySelector('.container')

function createGrid(rows, columns) {
for(r=0;r < rows * columns;r++) {
let div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = '';
container.appendChild(div).className = "div-element";
}
}

createGrid(16, 16);


let divElement = document.querySelectorAll('.div-element')

for(i=0;i<divElement.length;i++) {
  divElement[i].addEventListener('click', e => {
    divElement[i].classList.add("black")
  })
}
```

The issue is here when trying to use classList.add, I am unsure if it is because of querySelectorAll, the loop, or the EventListener

**CSS**

```
.title {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
font-size: 40px;
margin-bottom: -50px;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(16, 52px);
  margin-top: 100px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.div-element {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

.div-element:hover {
  background-color: black;
}

.buttons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
  gap: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.button-text {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 15px;
}

.hover {
  background-color: red;
}

.black {
  background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: The answer is `for (let i = 0; ...`. Make sure you're writing JavaScript code in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) to avoid such issues